# Question on CSS Media Query

Tags: javascript, html, css, w3c, media-queries

I have a question on CSS media query..

I am implementing a HTML page using desktop.css and ipad.css and want them in 2 separate file..
In desktop.css, I use @import url("ipad.css"); and also add @media not only screen and (device-width:768px) block which has the actual desktop styles..

So desktop.css looks like

```
@import url("ipad.css");

@media not only screen and (device-width:768px)
{
//Desktop styles
}
```

Now while the iPad CSS gets applied correctly on the iPad, for some reason the CSS for desktop does not get applied..
Not sure what is wrong with the "@media not only screen ..."

I referred http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries

and it says " The presence of the keyword ‘not’ at the beginning of the media query negates the result. I.e., if the media query had been true without the ‘not’ keyword it will become false, and vice versa. "

But for some reason, the desktop never renders the styles...Please help..Thank you..

**********EDITED*********

What might be the issue with using this approach ?

```
@import url("desktop.css") screen;
@import url("ipad.css") only screen and (device-width:768px);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like

`@media only screen and (device-width: 768px) {
/* desktop styles here */
}`

So, lose the `not` as that is what's making the rule apply to everything but the screen i.e. the desktop in your case.

Comment: I tried the same (@media only screen and (device-width: 768px)) and it does not work on desktop (IE and FF)...

Answer (score 1):

Following link could be helpfull.
[media-queries at developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries)
[media-queries at css3.info](http://www.css3.info/preview/media-queries/)

Answer (score 0):

`only screen` means that just screen and nothing else renders this. The `not` negates this so that everything but `screen` will render it.

Answer (score 0):

Do it either this way:

```
  <style type="text/css">
   @import url("desktop.css"); 
   @import url ("ipad.css"); 
   </style>
```

Where desktop.css starts without any @ media query rules, and ipad.css starts with
`@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {/*your code here*/}`  rule.

Or simply link to both like would you normally do, having ipad.css below desktop.css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/desktop.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ipad.css"/>
```

Where also you start the desktop.css file without any @ media rules and ipad.css starts with a `@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {/*your code here*/}`  rule.

This way, all desktop browsers will read the desktop.css file, and browsers that support media queries will also read the ipad.css (when the screen resolution is below 768px).

If you use them as you describe in your edit, IE8 and below will make a mess of it, it is well explained in this article => http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/safe-media-queries/

And if you want IE to also re-size and understand your media queries, the only way to solve the problem is by using this lightweight JavaScript library => http://filamentgroup.com/lab/respondjs_fast_css3_media_queries_for_internet_explorer_6_8_and_more/ that will do the magic for you (and basically make possible to work wit IE like with a normal browser) :)

The problem is that you can only make IE ignore the media queries so that that it wont mess up your sites look. To make IE understand media queries and re-size and adept with changes in window size you need help from the library I mention.

Comment: Thx a lot..I just tried the code..But for some strange reason, it seems to be working fine in Firefox, but not in IE8..

Comment: Try to change the order of the CSS style sheets - start with the desktop styles, without any fancy rules, and than put the ipad styles in a   @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {}.

Comment: Hey Husar..Actually I cannot change the order of the CSS style sheets ..reason being I am using @import for ipad.css which has to be in the beginning and I want the 2 to reside in separate files (i.e. desktop and ipad)

Comment: Well... import the desktop one at the begin of the ipad one :) Or just ditch import and use them as two separate files. The desktop one containing you desktop resolution styles and the ipad one - starting with the above media query rule - your below 764px rules.

Comment: Even that does not help in IE8..For some reasons, IE8 does not understand @media screen and (min-width: 768px)

Comment: Do you perhaps have some other media query rule in your style sheets? Also try this link => http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/safe-media-queries/ has lot of useful info.

Comment: ok..Then what should one don for IE8 (apart from user-agent) ?

Comment: I mean are you saying IE does not support CSS media queries at all ?

Comment: IE does support them only that it does in strange and mysterious ways that are hardly comprehensible. :) Anyway have you tried to link to your desktop styles like you would do normally (no media queries) and than, at the end of the desktop styles, apply @import("ipad.css). The ipad.css file should start with the media query i told you before, only change min for max (  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {} ). This way all the desktop browsers should read the desktop css files and if the screen gets smaller than 768px, the ipad rules should modify the page for the lower resolution.

Comment: The above is if you need IE to correctly display the desktop styles. But if you want IE to display the IPad styles as well (below window size of 768px) you will have to include the following JS library => http://filamentgroup.com/lab/respondjs_fast_css3_media_queries_for_internet_explorer_6_8_and_more/ . Don't worry, it is quite lightweight :)

Comment: You say "at the end of the desktop styles, apply @import("ipad.css). "

But I think we can only apply @import at the start and not at the end...

Comment: Import both. But import ipad.css after desktop.css (after desktop.css ends.). <style type="text/css">@import url("desktop.css"); @import url "ipad.css"; </style> . Or just link to the two file like you would normal do, one after the other.

Comment: I edited the first post to include all the comment info. Not I think it is quite clear.

Comment: ok..I got the approach which you are saying and I understand it will work..The only issue being it will unnecessarily load twice the styles..So my only question to you now is; what might be the issue if I use the approach I have included in my edited question ?

I'll close out the question as soon as I get an answer on this..

Comment: IE will make a mess from it since it will apply both styles. it is explained well here => http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/safe-media-queries/

Comment: How exactly can IE satsify the 2nd media thing..@import url("ipad.css") only screen and (device-width:768px);

Comment: With JavaScript... Read my original post, I added some stuff at the end. You can only make IE ignore the media queries and not mess up your sites look without hacks. To make IE understand media queries and re-size and adept you need help from the library i mention.

Comment: Fair enough..I understand that you are saying including the JS will work for IE..But my question is it is working without the need of the JS, if i code as mentioned in the "EDITED" section of my original question. (I have tested in IE).i.e. simply saying @import url("desktop.css") screen;

So my simple question is "can this approach create any problem"? If yes, what?

Comment: Yes, IE7 wont read your CSS at all. Plus it wont be re-sizable for desktop browsers. Check for yourself its only a few lines of code ;)

Comment: Hey Husar..You are bang on target..@import url("desktop.css") screen   does not work in IE7..Sounds strange, but I had read somewhere that IE7 does not support media query (but atleast supports type)..
I might have to try some other technique for IE7..